# Why isn't my Modal failing to appear on the screen in React Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, modal-dialog

As the question states, I'm trying to create a simple Modal with Bootstrap for my React Project. However, the modal fails to appear after I click the button which is supposed to activate the Modal.

Here is the code for my LoginPage.js. This is the component that is rendered via ReactDOM.render in my index.js file.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, ButtonToolbar, Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
class LoginPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context);

      this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);
      this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);

      this.state = {
        show: false,
      };
    }

    handleClose() {
      this.setState({ show: false });
    }

    handleShow() {
      this.setState({ show: true });
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
        <p>Click to get the full Modal experience!</p>
        <Button bsStyle="primary" bsSize="large" onClick={this.handleShow}>
          Launch demo modal
        </Button>

        <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.handleClose}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <h4>Text in a modal</h4>
            <p>
              Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula.
            </p>
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button onClick={this.handleClose}>Close</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      </div>
      );
    }
  }

export default LoginPage;
```

When I try to run it on the browser, this is what appears: [how it appears on my browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cS8CT.png). Clicking the button does absolutely nothing. No errors from the console and doesn't work on other browsers. I have bootstrap, bootstrap react installed and its listed as a dependency in my JSON file. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please read using guide in documentation for [react-modal](https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal) and code for [example modal](http://reactcommunity.org/react-modal/examples/minimal.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the props to hide and show the modal is `isOpen`

[reactstrap.Modals](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/modals/)